# Why this variable go out of scope, JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

```
function foo(){
    var bar = 0;
    $("#dummy").click(function(){
          bar += 1;
     })
}
```

I thought the bar is inside the function foo, so it is always callable. However, the error message is that the variable bar is undefined. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: it is, but you're defining an onclick handler, which will run at some undefined point in the future. when that inner `bar+=1` function is called, it won't be "under" foo() anymore. it'll be its own little function floating off in space somewhere. `var bar; function foo() { ....}` would let it work.

Comment: The snippet you've provided should not generate the error you've described. If the snippet is generalized, can you provide some of your actual code? Or create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) that does demonstrate the error?

Comment: The click function is a call back function which doesn't hold variable `bar`. I may be wrong..

Comment: the code looks perfectly valid. as far as i know, javascript *does* support closures.

Comment: The provided example works as expected. It does not reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not out of scope.
You are defining your click handler within a function, so you'll have to call the function for anything to happen, but apart from that, the code you posted does not reveal why you should be getting that error.

Here's an example (I removed the jQuery):

```
<button>Add one</button>
<div>bar is: <span id="barCount">0<div></div>

function foo(){
  var bar = 0;
  document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(){
    bar += 1;
    document.querySelector("#barCount").innerHTML = bar;
  };
}

foo();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/FP3SS/)**